How to fix numba-scipy to work with scipy.special
I am trying to write a simulation that involves very large matrix multiplications and for loops. To speed up the process, I thought about using numba-scipy. After installing the package with conda, I tried running the following code
import scipy.special as sp
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def Grh_gtr(J2,t1,t2):
t = t1-t2
if t == 0:
    return -1j/2
else:
    return (sp.jv(1,J2*t)-1j*sp.struve(1,J2*t))/(2j*J2*t)

I got instead, the following error
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<ufunc 'jv'>) found for signature:
 
 >>> jv(Literal[int](1), int64)

I have also tried installing the numba-special package using pip, but it gives me the following error
ERROR: Failed building wheel for numba-special
  Running setup.py clean for numba-special
Failed to build numba-special
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (numba-special)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Numba can only speed up basic Python code with Numpy functions and very few Scipy ones (certainly not sp.jv). If you cannot vectorize the operation so to work on arrays, then the usual solution is to reimplement the function (or use a native C/C++ library and call it from Python thanks to cython or ctypes).

@JérômeRichard It appears that numba-special does indeed have an implementation for scipy.special.jv.

Oh I missed about this part of the answer indeed. That being said, numba-special seems not maintained anymore since 5 years and developed by only 1 person (during only 5 days)... I also got a lot of issues while trying to install it and it seems not compatible with new packages... I advise not to use it.

It looks like this project is meant to generate Numba function calling Scipy functions from Cython. You can use Cython directly instead of Numba if you are not bound to Numba yet, or do the same thing (Cython+Numba) specifically for jv. Note you will not get much benefit for this jv function because AFAIK cannot inline Cython functions nor do any optimization on it.

Assuming you have successfully installed numba-scipy.
The first error complains about a type mismatch.
According to the documentation, the supported signature for jv is as follows.
Supported signature(s): float64(float64,float64)

On the other hand, your use of jv is interpreted as follows.
 >>> jv(Literal[int](1), int64)

The first argument is interpreted as a literal int, and the second argument is interpreted as an int64 variable.
So an easy fix is to cast both to float.
@jit(nopython=True)
def Grh_gtr(J2, t1, t2):
    t = t1 - t2
    if t == 0:
        return -1j / 2
    return (sp.jv(float(1), float(J2 * t)) - 1j * sp.struve(float(1), float(J2 * t))) / (2j * J2 * t)

Note that casting from int to float is cheap, but it's not free.
It might be better to minimize it by making it a variable.
import scipy.special as sp
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def Grh_gtr(J2, t1, t2):
    t = t1 - t2
    if t == 0:
        return -1j / 2
    one = float(1.0)
    j2t = float(J2 * t)
    return (sp.jv(one, j2t) - 1j * sp.struve(one, j2t)) / (2j * j2t)


print(Grh_gtr(1.0, 2.0, 1.0))  # Also better to call with the float arguments if possible.

